# Does a for loop re-evaluate the functions in its body in each iteration?

Tags: java, c++, c, for-loop

When I write a simple for loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){}
```

in Java, C and C++, does it reevaluates myList.size() in each iteration or just for once at the beginning of the loop? If it reevaluates, does preevaluating size, i.e.,

```
int n = myList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){}
```

gives us something significant in terms of performance?

Comment: Which language? c++, c or java?

Comment: Pick a language. Each one you mentioned has a different specification document that governs how it's to behave

Comment: I'm asking for both C++ and Java as I stated in question.

Comment: In C and C++, optimization depends on the return type of the `size` function.  If the function returns a constant value *and* the optimization settings are set correctly, the function may be executed once.

Comment: C++ guarantees nothing, it's totally implementation/situation dependant. You can always disassemble the code on your chosen compiler if you want to be sure.

Comment: Oh, you ask for C++ and Java? So the C tag is spamming tags for attention to your question, got it.

Comment: @StoryTeller A typo my friend. C/C++ and Java. Don't be so edgy.

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++. Don't spread such nonsense.

Comment: @StoryTeller C, C++ and Java. 3 different languages. Hope that's ok with you.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Bjarne Stroustrup calls C++ "a superset of the C programming language" - so I think it's not that unreasonable to refer to C/C++.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas - Bjarne said it over 30 years ago. You should read more up to date material.

Comment: @StoryTeller: It's a larger superset now, but still a superset.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas - It isn't, and never was. `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` was always valid in C, and never in C++. And since 2011, the divide between the languages is even greater, neither is a subset of the other. Stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Good counter-example. But Bjarne would still call it a superset I think - although perhaps a slightly imperfect superset by this point.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas - Bjarne is human and therefore capable of error. He is wrong on this nowadays. And if you want more examples, there are several posts on the subject on SO. The divide is great, and you can't call something a super-set if it doesn't contain the other thing proper, it's just cheating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Java:

```
for (int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){}
```

The condition is evaluated during **each** loop iteration; so there is a slight performance gain by moving that call to `size()` in front of the loop.

But in Java you should prefer the for-each

```
for (Whatever thingy : list)
```

notation anyway (where possible).

You can read about in the Java language spec, chapter [14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1).

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that it is described in [JLS Sec 14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1).

Comment: Great having such a great proofreader in the background. Thanks!

Comment: Most compilers would optimize this by determining whether it's possible that the ending condition can change within the loop - if it can't then there no performance issue.

Comment: The java compilers do not do such kind of optimizations. In our world, the JIT does the heavy lifting on almost un-optimized bytecode. javac does simple things like constant folding, but not much more.

Answer (score 8):

In both C and C++, the controlling expression is evaluated on *each* iteration of the loop.

From section 6.8.5.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The statement
>
> ```
> for (clause-1; expression-2; expression-3) statement
> ```
>
> behaves  as  follows:  **The  expression `expression-2` is  the 
>   controlling  expression  that  is evaluated  before  each  execution 
>   of  the  loop  body.**   The  expression `expression-3` is evaluated  as 
>   a  void  expression  after  each  execution  of  the  loop  body.   If
>   `clause-1` is  a declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares
>   is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the
>   other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before
>   the first evaluation of the controlling expression.  If `clause-1` is an
>   expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first
>   evaluation of the controlling expression.

Section 6.5.3 of the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) contains similar verbiage.

So if your controlling expression involves a function call or some other potentially expensive computation **that won't change in the loop body**, you should evaluate it beforehand, store it in a variable, then use that variable in the controlling expression.

Comment: I don't know if I would say that you "should" call the function once and store it.  That may not necessarily save you any time.  Modern compilers and STL implementations probably have that call to the size() function highly optimized already..  It's also possible that the size of the list could be modified in the loop.  (It's not advisable to do that, but it's not impossible.)  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Also, as other answers note, it is possible for the compiler to optimize the call in the controlling expression, so it's not absolutely true to that that the controlling expression will always be evaluated every iteration.

Answer (score 3):

*Logically* the condition is evaluated on each iteration.

You can tell this from looking at your example, because the value of `i` in the expression changes each time.

In practice it could be language or implementation dependent. The compiler or runtime may be able to cache or optimise parts of the expression. You can't necessarily tell from looking at the code in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether myList is being modified inside the for-loop. Also, the compiler (especially in C) tries to optimize such code by moving the evaluation outside the loop. The optimization is also based on whether the object is modified inside the loop or not.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ there is no requirement in the standard to optimize the function call (e.g. only call once).

The compiler's optimization engine needs to know the return type of the `size` and whether or not the value will changed.  A difficult undertaking.

If you want the function to be called once, assign the result to a constant variable before the loop:

```
const size_t size = myList.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  // ...
}
```

All guarantees of off if the `myList` is changed within the loop.  The function `size` will need to be called for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with C/C++ only, and the correct answer is: Sometimes it is evaluated and sometimes it is not. The compiler guarantee that it will evaluate in every iteration an assembly code which it **THINKS IS EQUIVALENT** to your original code (but not really what you intended). If you compile the code in debug mode (no compiler optimizations) or your variable has keyword volatile in its definition or you change the size of the list then the condition (size of list) will be indeed evaluated every iteration. If however you compile with speed optimization, don't change the list in a loop then modern compilers are smart enough to store the size of the list in a register and not evaluate it every iteration. Moreover, the function list.size() will be inlined and will not actually invoke the costly function call.

Note that in multi-threading programming this is **disastrous**. One thread may append elements to the list while the other thread which iterates over the list will never see the new elements. To force evaluation the size of list must be defined as **volatile** (or you can use memory barriers if you are familiar with assembly). Anyways, when you compile your application for production be sure to enable compiler optimizations and the run time penalty of alleged function call in each iteration will be nullified.

Another issue: Some very aggressive compiler optimizations may even **unroll your loop**. For example if your list has a size of 403 elements the compiler may perform 100 iterations each having your in-loop code repeated 4 times + 3 iterations of another loop with your original code. So there will be total 103 iteration and not 403 (so it is impossible to argue whether code is executed in each iteration because its hard to define what is iteration).
Example of such aggressive optimizations: copying long strings or memory buffers. If you copy X bytes, on 64 bits machine it is actually faster to do X/8 iterations (copying 64bits at once) + a remaining 0..7 bytes in a separate loop. There are some processors which even support units of 128 and up to 512 bytes in a single operations

Last advise: It is very important to write an easy to understand code, so in this case I would use good suggestions in the answers above (about java list iterators) or deliberately save list.size() into temporal variable

`const in list_size = list.size()`

Just for easier readability/debugging